# Kotlin WASM: How to add links?

Tags: kotlin, webassembly

I am trying Kotlin Wasm and I would like to know how can I add a link on a button because there is not intents to call.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way.

```
val uriHandler = LocalUriHandler.current

uriHandler.openUri("https://www.google.com")
```